# Multi-step form is not going to the next step after reaching X step

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, parsley.js

I have a multi-step form, and I'm using ParsleyJS to validate the form fields.

```
<form id="main-form"
      action="process.html" method="post" role="form"
      data-parsley-validate>

  <section id="form-step-1" class="clearfix step1 visible">
    step 1
  </section>

  <section id="form-step-2" class="clearfix step2 hidden">
    step 2
  </section>

  <!-- @@@@@ -->
  <!-- Here are unknown amount of sections generated dynamically. -->
  <!-- HTML output is generated dynamically and added by jQuery. -->
  <!-- I do ajax request and return here HTML code. -->

  <section id="form-step-last" class="clearfix step-last hidden">
    last step
  </section>

</form>
```

I do really have proper and valid prev and next buttons in each section, eg.:

```
<span class="btn btn-primary btn-nextstep next" data-current-block="2" data-next-block="3">Next</span>

<span class="btn btn-primary btn-prevstep prev" data-current-block="2" data-next-block="1">Previous<span>
```

In my test case I have a total of 10 sections, so they look like:

Hard-coded steps: `Step1 -> Step2 ->` then dynamically generated steps `S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9 ->` and the last step is hard-coded as first two.

If I'm in the 4th step (4th section) and click a "Next" button, the button is not working and doesn't take me to the 5th step (5th section).
The 4th step (4th section) is the 2nd step (2nd section) from dynamically generated steps (sections).

I think that the problem lies in this jQuery code:

```
$('#main-form').on('click','.next,.prev', function() {
  var current = $(this).data( 'currentBlock' ),
      next    = $(this).data( 'nextBlock' );
  // only validate going forward. If current group is invalid, do not go further
  // .parsley().validate() returns validation result AND show errors
  if( next > current )
    if( false === $('#main-form').parsley().validate( 'step'+current ) )
      return;
    $('.step' + current).removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
    $('.step' + next).removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
});
```

I tried to debug it in some ways, eg. deleted the `return;` line.
The result was that it added `visible` class to each next step, but after reaching 4th step and clicking next the current 4th step gets `hidden` class and the next 5th step gets `visible` class normally.

Weird?

I've made a screencast that will let you understand more easily my issue.

**[LINK](http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c26qF7eQX8)**

I get tired of it already for several hours and can't find a solution for this problem ;/ Hope you guys can help me out with this weird issue. Thanks.

Comment: You have `$('.step' + current).removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');` which means that all sections should be hidden after validation. The way I see it, only step4 is working correctly. Can you post your code in a fiddle (javascript, form html and buttons)?

Comment: @milz The site is live. http://rr171.stronazen.pl/zsform/

In the first form field type: "r171", the other fields can be random. I'm trying to figure it out from 2 days with no results. Maybe a fresh eye can see sth :)

The 4th next (Dalej) can't go further ;/

Comment: I've added `console.log($('#main-form').parsley().validate('step'+current));` after `if( next > current )` and every step returns true in console, but 4th step returns false. No idea why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you state in your comment `$('#main-form').parsley().validate('step4')` returns false. This is because step4 is validating two fields instead of 1, as you would expect.

In your console, if you write this: `$("[data-parsley-group=step4]")` you will see those two input fields. In the following image, you can see the DOM where the other field is:

[image: DOM inspector of the incorrect field]

As you can see, the field with the name "email_address", that one would expect to be validated in step10, is actually validated in step4. This is because the attribute `data-parsley-group="step4"`. If you remove this attribute it will validate correctly.

---

If you ever come across similar situations, using `$.listen` is a very good way to debug what's happening. I figured that step4 was validating two fields because I've added the following JS:

```
$.listen('parsley:field:error', function(parsleyField) {
    console.log(parsleyField.$element);
});
```

This way you can see in the console the fields that are not validated.

Comment: OMG Thank you! I spend 2 days figuring it out. And this was because my last step had `data-parsley-group="4"` and I didn't saw that, but I was thinking why this happens only in step 4? Now you cleared my minds. Once again thanks for your fresh eye :D